# Bootstrap Partial view modal form not submit

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-modal

i'm trying to create a form for add. i'm using bootstrap modal window to get data
here is my partial view

```
<div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">
                &times;
            </button>
            <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Register Datasource</h4>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
            @using (Html.BeginForm("Add", "DataSource", FormMethod.Post, new { id = "order-form", @class = "smart-form", novalidate = "novalidate" }))
            {
                <!-- modal data -->
            }
        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">
                Cancel
            </button>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">
                Add
            </button>
        </div>
    </div><!-- /.modal-content -->
</div>
```

on index page i'm firing modal show with button click

```
$('#btn-addDataSource').on('click', function() {
                var url = '@Url.Action("AddProvider","DataSource")';
                $.get(url, function (data) {
                    $('#register-modal').html(data).modal('show');
                });
            });
```

but when i submit the form it doesn't submit i used

```
$('#register-modal form').submit(function () {
    $.ajax({
        url: this.action,   
        type: this.method,
        data: $(this).serialize(),
        success: function (result) {
            if (result.success) {
                $('#register-modal').modal('hide');

            }
        }
    });
    return false;
});
```

what was i missed when i submitting please ??

Comment: Instead of button type="button" to change into  type="submit"

Comment: same nothing happens

Comment: the script is added at the end of the page, right ?

Comment: yeah that script added to end of page (not partialview but index)

Comment: In you code form  id = "order-form" but yours submit function id is $('#register-modal form') . can you change your id and try

Comment: i changed but not working

Answer (score 1):

Instead of button type="button" to change into type="submit"

```js
$('#order-form').submit(function () {
    $.ajax({
        url: this.action,   
        type: this.method,
        data: $(this).serialize(),
        success: function (result) {
            if (result.success) {
                $('#register-modal').modal('hide');

            }
        }
    });
    return false;
});
```

```html
<div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
       @using (Html.BeginForm("Add", "DataSource", FormMethod.Post, new { id = "order-form", @class = "smart-form", novalidate = "novalidate" }))
            {
        <div class="modal-header">
            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">
                &times;
            </button>
            <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Register Datasource</h4>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
           
            
        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">
                Cancel
            </button>
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">
                Add
            </button>
        </div>
          <!-- modal data -->
            }
    </div><!-- /.modal-content -->
</div>
```

Comment: Where you write the submit function? I mean that submit code inside the partial view or main view

Comment: submit function also write inside the partial view

Answer (score -1):

Its a hack but try submitting it by j-query. ie :

```
$(document).on("click", "#btnEdit", function(){
    $("#formEditCustomer").submit();
});
```